# Publish Test Results on Azure from Azure Storage account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-pipelines

I have a container that creates a report.xml file that I wish to use to create a test report in Azure.

I was thinking to do this during the pipeline, but I am missing how to get this file during the Azure pipeline.

What is the way to download a file in storage account and use it on a Test Result during the pipeline?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging this is the solution.

What I have done is mount a Storage volume during the container instances to my container that generates the report.

Afterwards in the pipeline I have copied the files that are stored in the storage account to the Pipeline agent.

```
$storageAcct = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName XXX -Name YYY
Get-AzStorageFileContent -Context $storageAcct.context -ShareName "Sharename" -Path "report.xml" -Destination $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

Then its just matter of getting that files from the agent when using the test reporter during the release pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you want to copy a file from blob storage in pipeline?

For that you can use [Azure Cli task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops) with this [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-download):

```
az storage blob download
```

But can you esplain what you mean by this `use it on a Test Result during the pipeline?`?

Comment: I want to use a file that is on my Azure Storage in a step that I use a step of Publish Test Results

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  Azure Powershell to  handle this get files from Azure Storage Blob:

```
$storage = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName xxx -Name yyy

$ctx = $storageAccount.Context



# download blob

Get-AzStorageblobcontent -Blob "report.xml" `

  -Container $containerName `

  -Destination " $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" `

  -Context $Context
```

---

According to this question:[How to copy a file from Azure Storage fileshare to Release pipeline agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690827/how-to-copy-a-file-from-azure-storage-fileshare-to-release-pipeline-agent)

Seems you were trying to download file from Azure File share (not blob), please simply refer my reply in that link.