# How to copy a file from Azure Storage fileshare to Release pipeline agent

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-files

I want to download a file that is on my Azure File storage in FileShare into my release pipeline agent.

[image]

Inside the release pipeline I am using a PowerShell step and run the command:

```
Start-AzStorageFileCopy    -SrcShareName "report.xml" -SrcFilePath "."  -DestFilePath "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)" -DestShareName  "report.xml" -Context $(context)
```

its asking me now for a parameter -name

```
2020-05-09T01:43:34.1007773Z ##[error]Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: Name.
```

Basically my plan is to use this file for a test report in a release pipeline. Therefore I need this file to be used in a Publish Test Result step.

[image]

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: It was a bit tricky, but if anyone else is having the same issue. 1 - Mount an Azure Storage account to the container. 2 - Copy the file to the mounted volume (had to put a sleep. the file was blank just after running my testcafe) 3 - run a Azure powershell and copy the file to the Agent working directory. 4 - Get the file On Publish Test Results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to download single report.xml file from Azure File Share, directly use `Get-AzureStorageFileContent` command.

Sample:

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext [storageaccountname] [storageaccountkey]

##sharename is your existed name.

$s = Get-AzureStorageShare [sharename] –Context $ctx

##To download a file from the share to the local computer, use Get-AzureStorageFileContent.

Get-AzureStorageFileContent –Share $s –Path [path to file on the share] [path on local computer]
```

If you want to download multiple files using one command, you could use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

More  detail info please take a look at this [blog](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/azure-files-how-to-manage-shares-directories-and-files/).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to download the file locally from the release agent job, so i would stick to using this command below:

```bsh
Get-AzStorageFileContent -Context $Context -ShareName "acishare" -Path "report.xml" -Destination $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```